# About WSGI header spoofing via underscore/dash conflation

Tags: python, django, http-headers, httprequest, uwsgi

I have a Django project deployed via apache/uwsgi. But things do not work as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META.

I would expect all request headers to be converted to "META keys by converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores and adding an HTTP_ prefix to the name", but instead they are not!

Does anyone know why? Is it possible the conversion is performed on http protcol only (not on https which I am using)? Is there any switch/configuration parameter that enable/disable this conversion?

Any hint explaining the behavior will be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your kind advice

Dario

P.S.: The following is the content of requirements.txt

certifi==2018.4.16
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
django-cors-headers==2.2.0
django-simple-history==2.0
djangorestframework==3.7.7
docker==3.5.1
docker-pycreds>=0.3.0
idna==2.6
mysqlclient>=1.3,<1.4
pycparser==2.18
pytz==2018.3
requests>=2.20,<2.21
six==1.11.0
urllib3>=1.23,<1.24
websocket-client==0.47.0
Django==2.1.2
gunicorn>=19.5.0,<19.6
django-filter==2.0.0
mozilla-django-oidc==1.2.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0